# Inject each element of an array to a different array

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays:

```
array1: [[1, 2], [2, 3]]

array2: ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I would like to combine those two and get the below result:

```
[[1, 2, "a"], [1, 2, "b"], [1, 2, "c"], [2, 3, "a"], [2, 3, "b"], [2, 3, "c"]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
array1.product(array2).map &:flatten
#=> [[1, 2, "a"], [1, 2, "b"], [1, 2, "c"], [2, 3, "a"], [2, 3, "b"], [2, 3, "c"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product) is purpose-built for this, but this is one alternative:

```
array2.flat_map { |e| array1.map { |arr| arr+[e] } }
```